# Routes have broken after upgrading from FuelPHP 1.0 to 1.7

Tags: fuelphp

After upgrading fuelPHP from 1.0 to 1.7 I am getting 404 when visiting one of my pages. This is my routes file:

```
return array(
    '_root_'  => 'home/index',
    '_404_'   => 'home/404',
    'item/(:identifier)' => array('item/index'),
);
```

My Controller:

```
class Controller_Release extends \Fuel\Core\Controller_Template
{

    public function action_index()
    {
        die('no response here');
    }
}
```

The home route is working but when I visit `example.com/item/turbo` I get the following error response:

`You can see this page because the URL you are accessing cannot be found.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with the following route format:

`'item/(:identifier)' => 'item/index/$1',`